# How can I store a cell height value in a Realm object that is associated with the cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm

I am using Realm Swift on iOS to store objects associated with `UITableViewCell`. Each cell is of a dynamic height, and I would like to store that height information in the Realm object as well. 
But unfortunately, I cannot put the code to update the cell height information in the notification block of the Realm object since it will trigger an infinite loop. I tried adding it to another class which creates some sort of foreign key relationship with the base object and that somehow triggered an infinite loop too as I try to update the other object in the notification block.

What would be the best way out for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Much like Cocoa's Key Value Observing, Realm's notifications indicate that an object was modified if you set any properties on the object, even if you set the properties to their existing values. This is likely what is triggering your notification loop. To avoid this, you can check within your notification block whether you're setting your cell height property to the same value that the object already has. If so, skip updating the property.

Comment: My problem is that the object is being updated, and thus I need to recalculate the height, which means I need to update the value of the height property in that very same object in the addNotificationBlock, which will trigger an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that'll produce an _infinite_ loop. Updating the height property will trigger another notification, but the second time the notification block is called your calculation of the height should give the same result since no other properties of the object changed. Detecting that you computed the same result and skipping setting the height property will result in exactly one extra call of the notification block.

Comment: In the addNotificationBlock, I perform a realm write to set the height to 0 to invalidate it. Then in the cell layout code, I perform a realm write to set the height to the correct value, which will trigger the addNotificationBlock code to run again, and I need to set the height to 0 again, and so on...

Comment: So you're _invalidating_ the cell height within the notification block and when you later recompute it you're triggering a new notification that causes the loop, rather than simply updating it within the notification block as you stated in your question. That makes me wonder why the cell height is something you're even storing in the Realm at all. Why bother saving it to disk at all?

Comment: A change in other properties in the realm object will trigger a height change, and I let Apple do its job of calculating the height again after invalidation. The height is used during estimatedheightforcellpath function if the height is not zero. IMO, its ok to update the height value all the time after cell layout anyway coz it does not trigger a full calculation, its just storing the value. But in this case, it triggers the infinite loop.

Comment: What I actually need is a function in the realm object that says do not observe the height property of the object.

Comment: Why store the cell height on disk? I'm not clear why that's useful. [Telling Realm to ignore the property](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#ignored-properties) will skip storing it on disk, and will also prevent notifications being triggered when the property is modified.

Comment: I need to store in disk so that when the app starts up again,it can just use the height that is calculated already. The height only being invalidated when there is a modification.